# strncmp doesn't return 0 on equal strings

Tags: c, strncmp

Shouldn't the `strncmp("end",input,3) == 0` return 0 if the input is end? It returns a number > 0 though.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *strArray[100];
  int strLengths[100];
  char input[100];
  int flag = 0;
  do {
    scanf("%c",&input);
      if(strncmp("end",input,3) == 0) {
        printf("end\n");
      }
      printf("%d\n",strncmp("end",input,3));
    } while(flag !=0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c",&input);` can't be correct, no matter the input

Comment: probably scanf includes a newline?

Comment: What if you replace `%c` with `%s`?

Comment: Use `scanf("%s",input);`

Comment: The `"%c"` format is to read a *single character*. It will be written into the first position of an array that is full of *indeterminate data* (which will seem random) without the ending null-terminator needed by all string functions.

Comment: Yes you were right @MathieuBunel it should be %s, thank you!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude *The "%c" format is to read a single character.*  Maybe.  By passing the address of an array for a `%c` format specifier, undefined behavior is invoked.  It *probably* does read a single `char` into the first element of the array.

Comment: You have an infinite loop since `flag` is never changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
scanf("%c",&input);
```

reads just a single `char` - maybe. It's wrong - pay attention to the errors and warnings you get from your compiler.

The format specifier is not correct - `%c` means `scanf()` will attempt to read a `char`, but you're passing the address of a `char[100]` array.  That's undefined behavior, so anything might happen.

You're also not checking the return value to see if `scanf()` worked at all, so you don't really know what's in `input`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the strings compared with `strncmp("end",input,3) == 0` will never match as `input` will contains only one character.

The call `scanf("%c",&input);` will read only the 1st character entered, and will store it in `input`

Comment: Accurate diagnosis.  Pity there’s no explicit prescription.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *strArray[100];
  int strLengths[100];
  char input[100];
  int flag = 0;
  do {
    scanf("%s",input);  //%c is for a single char and %s is for strings.
      if(strncmp("end",input,3) == 0) {
        printf("end\n");
      }
      printf("%d\n",strncmp("end",input,3));
    } while(flag !=0);
  return 0;
}
```

Next time print the input before continuing to confirm that you are doing it correct.

Comment: `&input` is still incorrect. You need to use just `input`